# CodeIgniter redirect not working on a real Server

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I'm having a problem with CI 2.1.3 redirect function.

Everytime I call redirect, it shows a white-blank page. In fact, it works well on my localhost, the problem just occurs on my real server (with CentOS 5 installed).

This is how I call the redirects :

```
redirect('frontend/article/index');

or

redirect(base_url('articles.html'));
```

I did add a route in config/routes.php

```
$route['articles.html'] = 'frontend/article/index';
```

with : frontend is module, article is controller, and index is action (I'm using [wiredesignz's HMVC module](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) extension)

How could I fix it? And what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I replaced CI redirect function by calling :

header("Location: http://example.com");

but it didn't work too.

So I created a file named info.php and uploaded it to my server. Here's the content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

When I type in the address bar : http://example.com/info.php, it shows like in the image.

[image]

Why was there a ">" character? Was it the problem causing redirect not working?

Comment: no need to use `base_url` on you're redirect. it will automatically append the base url when you are using `redirect`.

Comment: @tomexsans : Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't work even if I call redirect('frontend/article/index').

Comment: Turn on error reporting on your server, or try placing the following at the top of your index.php. `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` Also make sure you don't have any output (echo, print_r, print, dump, etc) before your call to redirect(). You should also check that your files don't have any whitespace at the bottom of them, it's known to cause problems when moving to a different environemtn.

Comment: @Jeemusu : Thanks for your reply. The space at the end of my helper caused the problem. Please answer the question and I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you again!

Comment: Thats great, keep an eye on that whitespace can't half cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure error reporting is enabled, or try placing the following at the top of your index.php.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

If this doesn't point you in the right direction make sure you don't have any output `echo`, `print_r`, `print`, `dump`, etc before your call to redirect() method.

Another common cause or problems when moving to a new environment is white space. Check that your files don't have any whitespace at the bottom of them.

Answer (score 1):

if you are defining .html in the config.php as the file ext. you do not need to postfix the route with it.

```
$route['articles'] //instead of $route['articles.html']
```

Also you need to remove the base_url() from the redirect cos that is not needed.

```
redirect('articles'); //should sort it
```

Hope this sorts ur problems.

## EDIT

If this is still not working after attempting these changes, it will most likely be a problem in the controllers. If this is the case you may need to turn on error reporting in your index.php file to find out exactly where the problem is occurring.